# Font or Word Art in Google Drawings

Tags: google-drive, google-drawings

I have a drawing in Google Docs. I want to change the font of a text box. Looking at the help page [How to use text in drawings](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179185), I see that apparently the only way to change the font is to use Word Art. It says in the previous link and in the answer [How do you get word art on Google documents?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_get_word_art_on_Google_documents) that I can insert Word Art, and it is the T symbol in the second row of Shapes, but I don't see it here:

[image: Shapes]

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's in the Insert menu:

[image]

Google should update their help page.